# How to find the duration of two time interval in php?

Tags: php

i have a Mysql table shift_def in the following format.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id   |   name   |   start_time   |    end_time   |   description   |  break  |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  101  | Shift1   |    01:03:55    |    06:00:55   |  Shift 1        |   1     |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  102  | Shift2   |    06:03:55    |    01:00:55   |  Shift 2        |   3     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

to find the total shift duration. i perform the following process in my php.

```
$shift_time = mysql_query("select start_time, end_time from rpt_shift_def where name ='Shif1'")or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($shift_time)) 
        {
           $Total_shift_time = strtotime($row['end_time']) - strtotime($row['start_time']);
            $hours=floor($Total_shift_time/3600);
            $Total_shift_time-=$hours*3600;
            $minutes=floor($Total_shift_time/60);
            $Total_shift_time-=$minutes*60;
            $seconds=$Total_shift_time;
            $Total_shift_time=$hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;*/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            echo "$Total_shift_time";
            echo "</br>";
        }
```

the output is

```
4:57:0
```

when i try the same for shift 2 the expected output is

```
18:57:0
```

but the output is

```
-6:57:0
```

the negative value is because end_time of the shift 2 is less than start_time.
how to solve this problem.

can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If end time is less than start time, add 24 hours (the reason being that the shift ended on the following day).

Since you have already calculated `$Total_shift_time`, you can just check if that is negative.

```
if( $Total_shift_time < 0 ) {
    $Total_shift_time += 86400;  // Number of seconds in a day
}
```

Err... Make sure you do this after you first calculate the shift time and before you start calculating hours, minutes and seconds...

Comment: that is the idea i also had. but its does't work. may be i was wrong in implementing. this is what i tried. `$in24hourstime = strtotime('+24 hours', $end_time); $Total_shift_time = strtotime($in24hourstime) - strtotime($row['start_time']);`. but its not working.